# Firebase reading a particular key values

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I have my username as a key for user data. Now I am trying to match the username with my current username stored in session storage and read the userdata for that username.

Here is my .js code

```js
var database = firebase.database();
var currentusername = sessionStorage.getItem("username");
var userref = database.ref("users");

  userref.orderByChild("username").equalTo(currentusername).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
 });
```

Firebase Data Structure

Appname

- Users

  - username: "a1"

    - email: " ",
    - firstname: "abc",
    - lastname: "xyz"

When I try to run the above code I am getting snapshot.val() as null although there exists a record with a matching username key.

Comment: Great to hear that you found the solution yourself. Please post it as a separate answer, instead of adding it to the question Stack Overflow is different from most fora, and having a separate (accepted) answer is the best way to show that your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var userref = database.ref("users/"+currentusername);

    userref.once("value").then(function(snapshot)
```

This worked!!!

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
var currentusername;
try {
    currentusername = sessionStorage.getItem("username");    
}
catch(error) {
    console.log("shucks " + error);
}

if(currentusername){
firebase.database().ref("users").child(currentusername).once('value').then(function(snap) {
        if(snap.val()){
            console.log(snap.val().firstname);
        }
    }, function(error) {
        // The Promise was rejected.
        console.log('Error: ',error);
    }); 
}
```